# localhost does not work when there is no internet connection

Tags: servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am creating servlet using Netbeans. The servlets do not run when i do not have an internet connection.I get a "Internal Communication Error".I did have a port conflict earlier which is now resolved.I am using Opera browser.Using the ip address instead of localhost does not work either.

Comment: Try to install some local service like mysql / apache and test if they communicate correctly on localhost. There can be networking problem on your computer. Is it windows / linux?

Comment: Its windows7. On port 8080 i have Oracle installed. and this also does not work offline.

Comment: Then I am sorry but this question does not belongs to developers QA forum but windows-networking QA forum.